# Is there a way to use a custom learning function for Artificial Neural Networks in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, hill-climbing

Is there a way (using just the R programming language) to implement an ANN algorithm with using a custom learning function (instead of backpropagation)? All of the R packages I have tested (nnet, neuralnet, AMORE) seem to have options for learning functions to train the weights, but none of them seem to include the optionality to plug in a custom function (say, hill climbing as an example).

I'd prefer to use R over another language, so if anybody knows of any package that can help, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `nnet` doesn't use backprop; it uses a quasi-Newton algorithm (basically BFGS) to optimise the weights.

Answer (score 0):

OBSERVATION:

[Hill Climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) is an **optimization algorithm** which works on **neighbours** and [Backpropogation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) is a **training algorithm**. Typically ANN packages use training methods to adjust weights based on error between two outputs:- **it does not optimize (or replace weights) based on neighbors**. That's why you'll only find *options for learning functions to train the weights but none for training via hill climbing or so*. This is by design

SOLUTION:

Use **custom mathematics** by means of input vectors, output vectors, matrix of node cells, in *any language* to have **Hill Climbing ANN** or so and iterate weights.

If not convinced for scratch implementation have a look at [simple hill climbing](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1339-simple-hill-climbing) in MATLAB. Am sure this will be re-writable in R